# vscode install go dev extension error in macos 12 ? "linux_syscall.c:67:13implicit declaration of function 'setresgid'"

Tags: go, vscode-extensions

## linux_syscall.c:67:13: note: did you mean 'setregid'?

runtime/cgo
linux_syscall.c:67:13: error: implicit declaration of function 'setresgid' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
linux_syscall.c:67:13: note: did you mean 'setregid'?
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include/unistd.h:593:6: note: 'setregid' declared here
linux_syscall.c:73:13: error: implicit declaration of function 'setresuid' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
linux_syscall.c:73:13: note: did you mean 'setreuid'?
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include/unistd.h:595:6: note: 'setreuid' declared here